External monitor not detected, Windows does, Ubuntu not
I have a suggestion for a new version of Ubuntu. Make it easier to detect an external monitor. I have an HP Z-book with a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 and the suggested NVIDIA driver (proprietary, tested). Ubuntu did not recognize the external monitor. When I dual boot to Windows, I can use the external monitor without problems.
Before the fresh install I have used Ubuntu 22.04 and I have tried almost every suggestion placed on forums like this to activate the external monitor but it never worked, hence I've promised myself that I stop trying.
Please make the use of an external monitor plug-and-play.
Thanks,
Hans

Hello Hans and welcome to ask ubuntu. You did not provide any information with regard to how the external monitor is connected. I have never encountered a situation where connecting an external monitor was not plug and play on Ubuntu. The only case where drivers were needed, was when a displaylink hub was used.

Try selecting xorg at login (at password prompt, select the gear icon in lower right corner). I find Wayland might have problems with external monitors when the displays are "joined", so if you must use Wayland, try "mirrored".

Oops, I used to use a HDMI cable from the laptop to the monitor. Now I use the Port Replicator from HP (HP 3005pr USB3.0 Port Replicator). If I connect directly via HDMI it works like a charm, via the port replicator it doesn't work. Thanks for answering. This item can be closed as far as I'm concerned.

You may accept you own answer (maybe after a bit of a delay) helping others and gaining some reputation points in the process.
